# Can't get centered text with css

Tags: html, css

OK, I known it is a know problem with known solutions but I can't get it to work on my page.
So I have a simple html:

```
<div id="sloganctnctn">
    <div id="sloganctn">
        <p id="slogan">
            A long line that can go to several lines on small width...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#sloganctnctn
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px;
    font-family: hos;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    color:#378de2;
}
#sloganctn
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    line-height: 105px;
}
#slogan
{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2;
}
```

But that doesn't work, see on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sw3Jd/600/

Thanks

Comment: remove `line-height: 2;`.

Comment: Vertically centered?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS Flex to achieve the desired effect by aligning the flex items to the center of the flex container. I have commented the CSS so that you can see what I have added/changed in the below example. I have also applied a background colour to the body so that it is easier to see the center alignment in the jsfiddle example.

```css
html{
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0;
}
body{
    font-size:1rem;
    margin:0;
    background:#EBEBEB;
}
div{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#head{
    width:100%;
    height:105px;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
}

#sloganctnctn{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;/** ADDED **/
    right:0;/** ADDED **/
    font-family: hos;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    color:#378de2;
  
    /** ADDED BELOW SECTION **/
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#sloganctn{
    /** REMOVED SOME STYLES HERE **/
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

#slogan{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="head">

  <div id="sloganctnctn">
    <div id="sloganctn">
      <p id="slogan">
        A long line that can go to several lines on small width...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, I still don't know why my solution did'nt work but maybe it's a more actual solution. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Change `#sloganctn`, `#slogan` to:

```
#sloganctn
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#slogan
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bd15p9x6/
Or change `#slogan` to:

```
#slogan
{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o80hz2pg/